# Periodogram in MATLAB and Python scipy gives different results?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I am trying to implement periodogram in Python. But the result is different from MATLAB. How can I make the result matching?

MATLAB code:

```
Fs=8000;
y1=zeros(1,256);
for f =0:100:1900
    for n=0:255
      y1(n+1)=y1(n+1)+sin(2*pi*f*n/Fs);
    end
end
[Sxxk,w] = computeperiodogram(y1,hamming(256),256);
display(Sxxk);
```

Result:

```
Sxxk =

    0.0153
    0.0257
    1.0230
   14.6425
    4.9626
    0.1737
    ...
```

Python code:

```
Fs=8000
sample=256
frequencys=100 * np.arange(20)

y1=np.zeros(sample)
for f in range(frequencys.size):
    for n in range(sample):
        y1[n]=y1[n]+sin(2*pi*frequencys[f]*n/Fs)


f, tmp_periodogram = signal.periodogram(tmp_sig,
                    window=np.hamming(256), nfft=256 , detrend=False)
print(tmp_periodogram)
```

Result:

```
    [  9.59750208e-02   1.61666495e-01   6.42745227e+00   9.20012900e+01
   3.11810128e+01   1.09163906e+00   7.78876698e+01   4.90721979e+01 ...
```

I have seen the post [Periodogram in Octave/Matlab vs Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130795/periodogram-in-octave-matlab-vs-scipy)

But it doesn't give an answer how to get results same as in MATLAB. Could someone please share their ideas?

Comment: I'd like to point out that the accepted answer does exactly answer your question, hence I'll vote to close this.

Comment: What is `computeperiodogram`?